# Compare pandas dataframes by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to figure out how two dataframes differ based on a combination of multiple columns. So if I have the following:

df1:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 3
1 3 4 2
```

df2:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 3
1 3 5 2
```

Want to show all rows where there is a difference such as (3,4,2) vs. (3,5,2) from above example. I've tried using the pd.merge() thinking that if I use all columns as the key to join using outer join, I would end up with dataframe that would help me get what I want but it doesn't turn out that way.

Thanks to EdChum I was able to use a mask from a boolean diff as below but first had to make sure indexes were comparable.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('A')
df2 = df2.set_index('A') #this gave me a nice index using one of the keys.
                  #if there are different rows than I would get nulls. 
df1 = df1.reindex_like(df2)
df1[~(df1==df2).all(axis=1)] #this gave me all rows that differed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html#pandas.DataFrame.all) and pass `axis=1` to perform row comparisons, we can then use this boolean index to show the rows that differ by negating `~` the boolean index:

```
In [43]:

df[~(df==df1).all(axis=1)]
Out[43]:
   A  B  C
1  3  4  2
```

breaking this down:

```
In [44]:

df==df1
Out[44]:
      A      B     C
0  True   True  True
1  True  False  True
In [45]:

(df==df1).all(axis=1)
Out[45]:
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

We can then pass the above as a boolean index to `df` and invert it using `~`

Comment: only thing is that my two dataframes are not identically labelled. `Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`. Is there a quick solution to this? Was thinking to a reindex_like perhaps?

Comment: So what exactly will be different the column names? The number of rows?

Comment: rows would be different. columns are same

Comment: In what way are the rows different? more or fewer rows or either?

Comment: it could be either fewer or more. basically get a new version of a dataset every month and want to be able to get a sense of how the records have shifted or changed in anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. using the .all and axis=1 did exactly what I wanted. I just make sure to first use my indexes properly. I've updated my question to show the steps I took.