# returning multiple columns after comparing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe as listed below. It was generated using pandas.

df1

```
                    0

0       reallocations
1                four
2              payoff
```

df2

```
word             frequency

whether          1
House            1
Sniderman        1
payoff           6
```

My goal here is to read `df1[0]` and check if it exists in `df2[word]` if it exists then give me an output in the following format.

```
word             frequency

four             0    
whether          1
House            1
Sniderman        1
reallocations    0
four             0
payoff           6
```

Here is what I have tried: `df1.intersection(df2)`. I believe I have to assign a column value for that.

I tried solution from [Compare pandas dataframes by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082004/compare-pandas-dataframes-by-multiple-columns)

I am pretty sure there is a small thing that not allowing me to concatenate the desired result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an *outer* join:

```
df1.rename(columns={'0': 'word'}).merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
# or df1.rename(columns={0: 'word'}).merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0) if column names in df1
# is a number

#   word            frequency
#0  reallocations   0.0
#1  four            0.0
#2  payoff          6.0
#3  whether         1.0
#4  House           1.0
#5  Sniderman       1.0
```

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps.